# MediaWiki: how to get the last N edited articles by a user?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mediawiki

Using PHP and MySQL, I am integrating a site with a wiki based on MediaWiki, so that profiles of users in the site have some stats about their contributions in the wiki.

I want to show **the last 3 edited articles of a user in a namespace (the main one, id 0), *without repeating*, and the links to them**.

In order to do that, I do more or less the following:

```
// getting the article IDs
$db->query("SELECT DISTINCT rev_page
        FROM revision r, page p
        WHERE r.rev_page = p.page_id
            AND p.page_namespace = 0
            AND rev_user = {$userId}
        ORDER BY r.rev_timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 3");
// then the IDs are stored in $last_edited_ids...

// getting the names of the articles
$db->query("SELECT page_title
        FROM page WHERE page_id
        IN (" . implode($last_edited_ids, ',') . ")");
```

The problem is that I am not sure it is correct, although it works *most of the time*: for some users, an old article shows as the last edited, but the 2nd and 3rd result are correct. That makes me thing I must be doing something wrong, but SQL is not my strong point...

Tip: if you don't know the MediaWiki database scheme (it is rather autoexplicative), you can have a look to it [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Mediawiki-database-schema.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "DISTINCT rev_page" clause is throwing your SQL off.  It is applying the DISTINCT to all of the rev_page (page.page_id's), so it will get a random rev_id per page.

Try this query, which combines your two queries into one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.page_title
FROM revision r, page p
WHERE r.rev_page = p.page_id
AND p.page_namespace = 0
AND rev_user = {$userId}
GROUP by p.page_title
ORDER BY MAX(r.rev_id) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: I see my mistake now. One more time, _if it looks too complicated, it is wrong_ :) 

Obviously, every 'rev_id' was different to another one in the table, so it was picking one randomly and causing problems. I wouldn't have thought about using ORDER that way! Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familliar with MediaWiki implementation, but I **guess** you should `ORDER BY` something else than `rev_id`. Maybe there's no guarantee the ids to be assigned chronologically. Isn't there some kind of `date` field in the `revision` table?

Then you could:

```
... ORDER BY r.date DESC ...
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was a typo from some tests I was doing :)
Right now I am using
    ... ORDER BY r.rev_timestamp ...
but the results are the same, so it doesn't look like a problem caused by that.